# inputAccessoryView hides after UIViewController view disappears

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I implemented docked `inputAccessoryView` like this:

```
lazy var inputView: UIView = {
    // custom creation
}()

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    return inputView
}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}
```

It works almost great, the issue is that `inputView` hides after I dismiss UIViewController (it is visible for 1 second, and then disappears).

Comment: post more code please

Comment: What do you mean by more? Code for inputView? Cause actually it is enough in UIViewController in order to see such behaviour.

Comment: or screenshot. Do you mean it is not hide with the other elements of UIViewController?

Comment: Exactly, it hides after one second. UIViewController is shown by present() method.

Comment: could you post a sceenshot?

Comment: Actually I can't, UIViewController view slides from top to bottom, and when the animation is done, inputView is also slides to bottom, instead of doing it in the same time. Funny thing is that when I'm showing this UIViewController with pushViewController method and then pop it, inputView slides from left to right together with UIViewController view.